# Infinitely decreasing exponents

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponentiation, infinity

Consider the following expression: $$x=a^{{\frac{1}{2}}^{{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{8}...}}}$$
Where $a$ can be pretty much anything. Normally, such exponents are evaluated from top to bottom. But this one goes infinitely. 
 So, would that expression even make sense? If yes, can something like that converge to a number?

Comment: The place to start is to try to find the limit (if it exists) of the sequence $\displaystyle ~(1/2), ~(1/2)^{(1/4)}, ~(1/2)^{\left[(1/4)^{(1/8)}\right]}, \cdots$

Comment: I think you can determine convergence/divergence from Theorem 7 (p. 157) in [*Infinite exponentials*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2300357) by David Francis Barrow (1936; [another copy](https://www.math.usm.edu/lee/BarrowInfiniteExponentials.pdf)). Also, there are similar questions in MSE (maybe mathoverflow), such as when the tower of exponents is the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

A simple python script will give you approximately 0.81 for the exponent of $a$.[image]

Interestingly, exponent partials appear to oscillate which would suggest that it will not converge.

[image]

Comment: That is assuming the exponent converges.

Comment: Try with `denom = 11` to see the issue, getting about $0.57$

Comment: Interesting, @Henry.  I can confirm.

Comment: If I go to 20, it jumps back to 0.81.  I think it;'s pretty easy to show that the exponent can never be greater than 1.  Issue seems to be ... is there a periodic behavior, and if so, why?

Comment: It is a parity issue.  $\left(\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)^{1/2^n} \approx 1$ for large $n$ so you wipe out pairs going down